# How to create a column from different dataframes?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have df1:

```
IDcode   Random
11       8
2        9
3        10 
18       3
21       2
6        4
9        5
10       4
```

I have a second df named Goats:

```
IDcode   Random
11       10
18       22
44       9
10       7
```

I have a third df named NotGoats

```
IDcode   Random
2        11
3        10
6        18
9        10
43       11
```

I would like to make a new Goat column in df1 that checks to see if the IDcode exists in the Goats df or the NotGoats df. If it exists in Goats df, I would like to have a value of 1, if it exists in NotGoats, I would like to have a value of 0. If it does not exist in either, I would like to have an NA.

Output would look like:

```
IDcode   Random  Goat
11       8       1
2        9       0
3        10      0
18       3       1
21       2       NA
6        4       0
9        5       0
10       4       1
```

Comment: 10 exists in both `Goats` and `NotGoats`, in that case what should happen?

Comment: @enke, good catch, fixed!

Comment: This is tagged with both [tag:r] and [tag:python]. Which is it? (Python doesn't have dataframes, so if this is for Python you probably want to use the [tag:pandas] tag.) Since you have also tagged [tag:dplyr] I'm going to guess this is mean to be for R. Please don't spam the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` `r` option:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(Goat = case_when(IDcode %in% Goats$IDcode == TRUE ~ 1,
         IDcode %in% NotGoats$IDcode == TRUE ~ 0))
```

**Output**

```
  IDcode Random Goat
1     11      8    1
2      2      9    0
3      3     10    0
4     18      3    1
5     21      2   NA
6      6      4    0
7      9      5    0
8     10      4    1
```

**Data**

```
df1 <-
  structure(list(
    IDcode = c(11L, 2L, 3L, 18L, 21L, 6L, 9L, 10L),
    Random = c(8L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L)
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,-8L))

Goats <-
  structure(list(
    IDcode = c(11L, 18L, 44L, 10L),
    Random = c(10L, 22L, 9L, 7L)
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,-4L))

NotGoats <-
  structure(list(
    IDcode = c(2L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 43L),
    Random = c(11L, 10L, 18L, 10L, 3L, 11L)
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,-6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check it like this:

```
import numpy as np

df1['Goat'] = np.nan
df1['Goat'] = np.where(df1['Goat'].isin(df_goats['IDcode']), 1, df1['Goat'])
df1['Goat'] = np.where(df1['Goat'].isin(df_no_goats['IDcode']), 0, df1['Goat'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative, in case you want to keep `Random` from difference sources.

Add a `Goat` column for your other data.frames (containing either 1 or 0), and combine with `bind_rows`. Then `left_join`.

```
library(tidyverse)

Goats$Goat <- 1
NotGoats$Goat <- 0

left_join(
  df1,
  bind_rows(Goats, NotGoats),
  by = "IDcode"
)
```

**Output**

```
  IDcode Random.x Random.y Goat
1     11        8       10    1
2      2        9       11    0
3      3       10       10    0
4     18        3       22    1
5     21        2       NA   NA
6      6        4       18    0
7      9        5       10    0
8     10        4        7    1
```